# Suppress the match itself in grep

Tags: regex, grep

Suppose I'have lots of files in the form of

```
First Line Name
Second Line Surname Adress
Third Line etc
etc
```

Now I'm using grep to match the first line. But I'm doing this actually to find the **second** line. The second line is not a pattern that can be matched (it's just depend on the first line). My regex pattern works and the command I'm using is

```
grep -rHIin pattern . -A 1 -m 1
```

Now the `-A` option print the line **after a match**. The `-m` option **stops after 1 match**( because there are other line that matches my pattern, but I'm interested just for the first match, anyway...)

This actually works but the output is like that:

```
./example_file:1:        First Line Name
./example_file-2-        Second Line Surname Adress
```

I've read the manual but couldn't fidn any clue or info about that. Now here is the question.

How can I suppress the match **itself** ? The output should be in the form of:

```
./example_file-2-        Second Line Surname Adress
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sed` to the rescue:

```
sed -n '2,${p;n;}'
```

The particular sed command here starts with line 2 of its input and prints every other line. Pipe the output of grep into that and you'll only get the even-numbered lines out of the grep output.

An explanation of the sed command itself:

`2,$` - the range of lines from line 2 to the last line of the file

`{p;n;}` - `p`rint the current line, then ig`n`ore the next line (this then gets repeated)

(In this special case of all even lines, an alternative way of writing this would be `sed -n 'n;p;'` since we don't actually need to special-case any leading lines. If you wanted to skip the first 5 lines of the file, this wouldn't be possible, you'd have to use the `6,$` syntax.)

Comment: Is that possible without piping to sed, but with the single grep command? Probably possible with `grep -P ...` (perl regular expressions)? I have heard about things like "look-around" and "look-ahead", but do not know about that much yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can use sed to print the line after each match:

```
sed -n '/<pattern>/{n;p}' <file>
```

To get recursion and the file names, you will need something like:

```
find . -type f -exec sed -n '/<pattern>/{n;s/^/{}:/;p}' \;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have already read a book on grep, you could also read a manual on **awk**, another common Unix tool.

In awk, your task will be solved with a nice simple code. (As for me, I always have to refresh my knowledge of awk's syntax by going to the manual (`info awk`) when I want to use it.)

Or, you could come up with a solution combining `find` (to iterate over your files) and `grep` (to select the lines) and `head`/`tail` (to discard for each individual file the lines you don't want). The complication with `find` is to be able to work with each file individually, discarding a line per file.

Comment: The posted above `sed` solution is simple and clear! I admit it'd beat my answer.

Answer (score -1):

You could pipe results though `grep -v pattern`